# How to stop remote debugging of Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-remote-debugging

I have a release version cordova application and trying to stop a chrome remote debugging. I have set setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(false) on webview but still it cant stop remote debugging on chrome:inspect. It is very strange that I have an app build in release version but chrome inspects still showing this application. Is there any way to block this feature and available only on demand?

Comment: Related: [How to disable remote android debugging of WebView in Ionic/Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40641095/295004). You might want to confirm that you checked your plugins for remote debugging being enabled.

Comment: I already checked this post but not found anything which can resolve this problem.